# JQuery fancybox does NOT display on jquery cycle?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

I am using this (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin. I would like to open fancybox modal only when users clicks an anchor tag inside of this div which is inside of the cycle. **Is there any jquery plugin that I can use instead of cycle? because it seems fancybox is not running with cycle.**

HTML:

```
<div id="right4" class="pics">
    <img class="img-center" src="images/smart-agriculture1.png" width="168" height="168" alt="Akıllı Tarım"/>
    <ul class="solutions-ul">
        <li lang="tr">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Gübreleme
        </li>
        <li lang="tr">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Şarap Kalite Artırılması
        </li>
        <li lang="tr">

            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery4" href="/images/flyers/smart_agriculture.jpg">Akıllı Tarım</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#right4").cycle({
    fx: 'curtainX',
    next: '#right',
    timeout: 0,
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
```

I would like to open fancybox when user clicks the a tag inside of div. Problem is fancybox does NOT open.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        autoSize: true,
        fitToView: true,


    });

});
```

Here is a sample codepen:
http://codepen.io/cenkkizildag/pen/rLezog/

Comment: fancybox doesn't work, I added the code sample.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately, No errors on the console.

Comment: Are you sure that cycle plugin can use elements other than images?

Comment: yes it does support other elements

Comment: should I use var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: @eboye is there any plugin that I can use instead of cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after (the effect), but I'm using Slick Slider wherever I can as it's pretty good for customization: [link](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)